# Crashlytic build error occured when android pakage in UE4

Tags: android, crashlytics, unreal-engine4

When I pakage a project for android with Ultimate mobile kit in UE4.24.
(Ultimate mobile kit not support 4.24 but I made it. Following ultimate mobile kit community) It made build fail.

I did settings for android as ultimate mobile instruction.
(Setting google-service.json in Project/Config/Firebase/Android and load, checking Upload dSYMs for Android in Project and enable crashlytic in Ultimate Mobile Kit Category.
Setting android SDK, NDK, minimum android apk level in Android SDK Category,
And Setting accepted android license in Android Category in Android Category.)

Here is a build fail log.

```
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple files matching Z:\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\arm64-v8a\libcrashlytics.so in Z:\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stripDebugSymbol were found. Is the -androidNdkLibsOut setting configured correctly?**
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.codemapping.csym.AndroidCSymIdStrategy.createCSymIdForFile(AndroidCSymIdStrategy.java:64)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.codemapping.csym.ElfCSymFactory.createCSymFromFile(ElfCSymFactory.java:94)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.codemapping.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:70)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.CSymManager.generate(CSymManager.java:96)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:692)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.gradleMain(DeveloperTools.java:292)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:367)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.this$2$callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$_crashlyticsGenerateSymbols_closure10.doCall(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:198)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:726)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:699)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:598][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.27:599][445]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): :app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease FAILED
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): :app:ue4CompleteRelease
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): 74 actionable tasks: 71 executed, 3 up-to-date
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): * What went wrong:
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease'.
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): > Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): * Try:
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 [2020.06.21-14.01.28:939][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): BUILD FAILED in 56s
 [2020.06.21-14.01.29:268][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): ERROR: cmd.exe failed with args /c "C:\Projects\Test\Intermediate\Android\APK\gradle\rungradle.bat" :app:assembleRelease
 [2020.06.21-14.01.29:268][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)):        (see C:\Users\lsh7f\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.24\Log.txt for full exception trace)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.29:268][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
 [2020.06.21-14.01.29:268][449]UATHelper: 패키징 (Android (멀티:ASTC,PVRTC,DXT,ATC,ETC2,ETC1)): BUILD FAILED
```

help me please

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here -

Whether you're setting the `-androidNdkLibsOut` field yourself or allowing the plugin to automagically find the paths itself, it looks like it's resolving to an architecture-specific directory, which looks to be why you're running into this error.

How are you setting your `-androidNdkLibsOut` and `-androidNdkOut` fields, if at all?

- if you're setting it yourself, don't set it to any architecture-specific directories
- if you're not setting it, or if you're setting it incorrectly, try the following:

`-androidNdkLibsOut \app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib`

instead of

`-androidNdkLibsOut \app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\arm64-v8a\`

If you're still having trouble, I recommend editing your original post to show your `build.gradle` block where you're setting Crashlytics NDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I will try your advice. 
And I found someting abnormal situation. 

1. when I pakage android in development mode with **deactive Automatic Symbols Upload for Android[Shipping] in Ultimate mobile kit category in project setting. Pakaging success. **
2. when I pakage android in development mode with **dective Automatic Symbols Upload for Android[Shipping] in Ultimate mobile kit category in project setting by Jenkins, pakaing fail.**

Comment: Hm, not sure I understand the situation between 1. and 2. or what you're trying to accomplish. Are these upload deactivations/activations specific to Crashlytics NDK?